# Get all activities' names from an explicit external application

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity

My code so far:

```
    val  listofApps:List<ApplicationInfo> = packageManager.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA)
    var test: Array<ActivityInfo>
    try{
        test = packageManager.getPackageInfo(listofApps.get(2).packageName, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES).activities
        var s: String = "App " + listofApps.get(2).packageName + " has activities: "
        for (activityInfo in test) {
            s = s + activityInfo.name + " "
        }
        Toast.makeText(this, s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }catch (e:Exception){
        Toast.makeText(this, e.message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
```

I get an exception because *test* is null. If I use *context.packageName* instead of *listOfApps.get(2)* it works as expected. I did not include the external app in the manifest, but since I will do this with all the apps installed on the phone, there might be new apps at some time I can't declare them, so I need a more **dynamic solution**.

## How can I fix the code so I can get all activities from the app ?

Answer (score 0):

**Edited based on your comments:**

I believe that's happening because *getInstalledApplications* will also return the package name of services that don't have any activities.

You first need to iterate over the list and then check if the package itself has any activity or not:

```
val installedApplications:List<ApplicationInfo> = packageManager.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA)
    var packageInfo: PackageInfo?
    var activities: Array<ActivityInfo>

    try{
        for (activity in installedApplications) {
            packageInfo = packageManager.getPackageInfo(activity.packageName, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES)
            if (packageInfo.activities != null) {
                activities = packageInfo.activities

                var result: String = "App " + activity.packageName + " has activities: "
                for (activityInfo in activities) {
                    result = result + activityInfo.name + " "
                }

                Log.d(TAG, result)
            }
        }

    } catch (e:Exception){
        Log.e(TAG, "${e.message}")
    }
```

Comment: This is what I am doing, instead of "specific.package.name" I have list.get(2).packageName

Comment: Yes, but that means that you can get an app with no activities - right? You're just accessing the application that is on the second element of the list. Shouldn't you iterate over listofApps?

Comment: I think I've understood the problem - the null that you're having it's not on a service? On the emulator it says that it's: com.google.android.ext.services

Comment: Updated my comment based on this.